# How to export worksheet to PDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print a tab in Excel as a PDF document to a specified folder. The path to the folder is listed on a separate tab in the same Excel doc.

I've used the below code before for other projects, but this time it isn't working.

```
letter = Worksheets("Variables").Range("O25").Value

If Range("f11").Value > 0 And Range("G3").Value = 5 Then
    MsgBox "THERE ARE ACCOUNTS THAT REQUIRE MANUAL MAINTENANCE."         
    Sheets("NEED End dates ").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=Trim(letter), Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False               
End If
```

I believe that the path listed out in `O25` is where the tab should be printing to, but nothing shows up in there, and I do not receive any error codes when running it.

There is data on the tab and so I can't see why it won't print. I've tried putting the  `letter =` piece inside of the if statement, but it also doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: are your cells `F11` and `G3` Set As number format in excel ? you can use `debug.print TypeName(Range("F11).Value)` and `debug.print TypeName(Range("G3).Value)` if it returns string you must convert your range as numerical value

Comment: what about adding more specific references when using ranges? add `Worksheets("Variables").` before every `Range`.

Comment: @Dorian still working thru it; your troubleshooting technique is appreciated.

Comment: @Dorian the debug.print is returning the #'s 1 and 5. Doesn't mention anything about string

Comment: @Dorian it says Double

Comment: @Lukec So maybe you can try using Cells("F11").Value and Cells("G3").Value and see what happen ?

Comment: The range piece seems to be functioning, as the macro moves down to the print function. And now I am getting a run time error on the print piece. Saying 'document not saved. Document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving'

Comment: Based on @Dorian's first comment, if you replace your if statement with this: `If Cint(Range("F11").Value) > 0 And Cint(Range("G3").Value) = 5 Then` what happens?

Comment: Have you checked the PrintArea?

Comment: Turns out the only problem was that i was including a date in the file name to which I was saving. I took out the date and then it worked fine. Any ideas how to incorporate a date (like today()) into a filename without getting an error?

Comment: @Lukec, `Format$(Now,"yyyy-mm-dd")`. If you want the time component as well, `Format$(Now,"yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")`.